# javascript if-else like php

Tags: php, javascript, html, if-statement

Is it possible to do an if-else in JavaScript with HTML content like in PHP?

If so, how?

Example

```
<?php
if(1) {
?>

<h1>thought so</h1>

<?php
}
else {
?>

<h1>that's strange</h1>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: How? I forgot to ask that, didn't I...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a direct translation to javascript. Not normally the right approach though.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if(1) {
      document.write('<h1>thought so</h1>');
}
else {
      document.write('<h1>that\'s strange</h1>');
}
</script>
```

---

Here's a better way:

```
<div id="show-if-true" style="display: none">
    <h1>thought so</h1>
</div>
<div id="show-if-false" style="display: none">
    <h1>that's strange</h1>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ifFalse = document.getElementById('show-if-false'),
    ifTrue  = document.getElementById('show-if-true');

if(1) {
    ifTrue.style.display = "block";
}
else {
    ifFalse.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible without the `document.write`?

Comment: Yes, it is. Why do you need this?

Comment: Note how @Eric mentioned not normally the right approach though.  And rightfully so, this is poor practice IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you are performing the `if/else` logic within javascript / jquery.
HTML is `wysiwyg`.

Comment: that's what I meant... in JavaScript...kinda like PHP does

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do:

```
if(something){
      //do something
      document.write('<h1>thought so</h1>'); //see comments below
}
else if(something_else) {
      //do something else
      document.write('<h1>that\'s strange</h1>'); //see comments below
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/mQytV/

Comment: can you do what I'm trying to do, with the `if` body being HTML?

Comment: is there a function for escaping?

Comment: @tekknolagi -- escaping what?

Comment: @tekknolagi just double it `''`

Comment: @Tekknology -- just use `"` instead of `'` to wrap the text

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot embed html in javascript. What php does it "print" the html as you go along on the server, javascript can't do that - it can't actually generate html. That's what the DOM interface is for.

Comment: Oh sorry, I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misread you. This is very possible in javascript, but might I suggest using jQuery instead? jQuery is a very powerful, widely used javascript framework.

In jQuery you can call and DOM element and set the HTML inside it with a simple .html("asdasda") like syntax! And ofcourse you have if - else, foreach, switch, etc.

This is very possible, however the degree of conditions you can validate is limited since you cannot define variables, etc in HTML (before HTML 5).

You can refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx

Basically they syntax is  HTML CONTENT

Where HTML content will be hidden on true conditional outcome.

Let me know if you have any particular code in mind to do this for.